# How to obtain the self increasing ID of batch inserted data without passing parameters?

Tags: mybatis

### environment

mybatis  3.4.6

### Target class

org.apache.ibatis.executor.keygen.Jdbc3KeyGenerator.class

### Question

Obtain the self-increasing ID of the Batch Insert data, which will be set to the elements of the List collection. How should I obtain self-increasing IDs if I use the following SQL:

```xml
<insert id="test" parameterType="java. util. List" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="id">
 Insert into test (name) (select menuName as name from menu)
</insert>
```

```java
public int  test(List<Map> maps);
```

I don't know how many pieces of data were actually inserted here, and due to performance reasons, I don't want to query how many pieces of data will be executed under the current conditions. My parameters cannot set specific elements

### Bug Position

I checked the source code and found that it is located at line 60 of the  `org.apache.ibatis.executor.keygen.Jdbc3KeyGenerator.java`
file. The code sets the echo ID based on the number of parameter elements, instead of using the  `ResultSet rs`  variable to obtain the number of SQL operation data lines to generate the ID. Can we optimize it here?

```java
public void processBatch(MappedStatement ms, Statement stmt, Collection<Object> parameters) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
      rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
      final Configuration configuration = ms.getConfiguration();
      final TypeHandlerRegistry typeHandlerRegistry = configuration.getTypeHandlerRegistry();
      final String[] keyProperties = ms.getKeyProperties();
      final ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
      TypeHandler<?>[] typeHandlers = null;
      if (keyProperties != null && rsmd.getColumnCount() >= keyProperties.length) {
       // 这里循环参数的元素          是否可以改成:  如果 List 参数的元素个数为空，使用 while(rs.next) 往 List 容器中添加元素
        for (Object parameter : parameters) {
          //There should be one row for each statement (also one for each parameter)
          if (!rs.next()) {
            break;
          }
          final MetaObject metaParam = configuration.newMetaObject(parameter);
          if (typeHandlers == null) {
            typeHandlers = getTypeHandlers(typeHandlerRegistry, metaParam, keyProperties, rsmd);
          }
          // 设置一行的数据到 List 类型参数的元素中。
          populateKeys(rs, metaParam, keyProperties, typeHandlers);
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new ExecutorException("Error getting generated key or setting result to parameter object. Cause: " + e, e);
    } finally {
      if (rs != null) {
        try {
          rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // ignore
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

### environment

mybatis  3.4.6

### Target class

org.apache.ibatis.executor.keygen.Jdbc3KeyGenerator.class

### Question

Obtain the self-increasing ID of the Batch Insert data, which will be set to the elements of the List collection. How should I obtain self-increasing IDs if I use the following SQL:

```xml
<insert id="test" parameterType="java. util. List" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="id">
 Insert into test (name) (select menuName as name from menu)
</insert>
```

```java
public int  test(List<Map> maps);
```

I don't know how many pieces of data were actually inserted here, and due to performance reasons, I don't want to query how many pieces of data will be executed under the current conditions. My parameters cannot set specific elements

### Bug Position

I checked the source code and found that it is located at line 60 of the  `org.apache.ibatis.executor.keygen.Jdbc3KeyGenerator.java`
file. The code sets the echo ID based on the number of parameter elements, instead of using the  `ResultSet rs`  variable to obtain the number of SQL operation data lines to generate the ID. Can we optimize it here?

```java
public void processBatch(MappedStatement ms, Statement stmt, Collection<Object> parameters) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
      rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
      final Configuration configuration = ms.getConfiguration();
      final TypeHandlerRegistry typeHandlerRegistry = configuration.getTypeHandlerRegistry();
      final String[] keyProperties = ms.getKeyProperties();
      final ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
      TypeHandler<?>[] typeHandlers = null;
      if (keyProperties != null && rsmd.getColumnCount() >= keyProperties.length) {
       // 这里循环参数的元素          是否可以改成:  如果 List 参数的元素个数为空，使用 while(rs.next) 往 List 容器中添加元素
        for (Object parameter : parameters) {
          //There should be one row for each statement (also one for each parameter)
          if (!rs.next()) {
            break;
          }
          final MetaObject metaParam = configuration.newMetaObject(parameter);
          if (typeHandlers == null) {
            typeHandlers = getTypeHandlers(typeHandlerRegistry, metaParam, keyProperties, rsmd);
          }
          // 设置一行的数据到 List 类型参数的元素中。
          populateKeys(rs, metaParam, keyProperties, typeHandlers);
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new ExecutorException("Error getting generated key or setting result to parameter object. Cause: " + e, e);
    } finally {
      if (rs != null) {
        try {
          rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // ignore
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Cross posted : https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/2942